# Android Send SQLite table data to XAMPP server

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, synchronization, xampp

I want to send SQLite table data to PHP Server. Problem is that when i send single row of table it successfully upload in server but when I send bulk row, it will send last row of table in every while loop.
I want to send all my table data to the Server but this code is not working as expected. I am new in this so please help me.

**Class with AsysncTask**

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.b_sync:
        ArrayList<String> data = hp.getSaveOpInfo(getContext());
        String opid = data.get(0);

        //Create Database Connect Object "dbConnector"
        DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(getActivity());

        if(!dbConnector.isPayTableEmplty()) {
            // open DB for operation
            dbConnector.open();
            // get customer Table columns
            Cursor cr = dbConnector.fetchAllPayment();
            //  cr.moveToNext();
            while(cr.isAfterLast()==false){

                // get Data from Payment Table
                getCon = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(dbConnector.CONNO));
                paid_amt =cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(dbConnector.PAIDAMT));
                discount =cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(dbConnector.DISCOUNT));
                contact =cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(dbConnector.CONTACT));
                lnid =cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(dbConnector.LNID));
                time =cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(dbConnector.TIME));


                // Create param for POST
                params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "payment"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("conNo", getCon));//getData.getString("con")));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("amount",paid_amt)); //getData.getString("paid_amt")));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lineman", lnid));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("opId", opid));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", time));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile",""));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("receipt", "0"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("discount", discount));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sms_ovr", "0"));

                // AsyncTask Class
                new ReadJSONResult().execute(sync_url);

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), params.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                cr.moveToNext();
            }

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Empty Data ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        dbConnector.close();
        break;
    }
}

class ReadJSONResult extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return cn.readJSONFeed(urls[0],params);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //   Toast.makeText(getContext(),"RESULT="+ result.toString(),
        //        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(getActivity());
        try {
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //   Toast.makeText(getContext(), result.toString(),
            //  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

            if ("1".equals(jsonObject.getString("success"))) {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        "success =  \n "+jsonObject.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // dbConnector.deletePayMentTable();
                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        "Account Not Found \n Please try again.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Ex", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "onPost == " + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: What you want to do exactly?

Comment: i want to send all table rows to XAMPP Server

Comment: all rows of single table or all table all rows?

Comment: all rows of a single table

Comment: Why you are not using JSON for post data to server?

Comment: ok but i want to know that this code working properly or not after some changes with while loop

Comment: if you want send table data as json parameter then I will post an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96118/discussion-between-rahul-dev-and-amy).

Comment: Instead of sending one `JSONObject` at a time, why don't you form `JSONArray` and send it in bunch.